# What happens under NATO Article 5 if a state involved in a war (like Ukraine) joins NATO?

Tags: russian-federation, ukraine, nato

Why would Ukraine joining NATO at the present time not result in an immediate state of war between NATO members and Russia because of Article 5 obligations to defend a member state under attack? I always assumed that peace between Russia and Ukraine was an implicit precondition of Ukrainian membership for this reason. Yet proponents and opponents of NATO membership for Ukraine don’t seem to assume it would *necessarily* bring the US and most of Europe into the war right away. What understanding of Article 5 leads to this assumption?

Or is there a provision to prevent this scenario? I’m thinking specifically in terms of the treaty obligations, not other geopolitical considerations.

What inspired the question: this editorial https://www.wsj.com/articles/ukrainians-die-as-america-dawdles-russia-putin-nato-kgb-war-aid-weapons-europe-membership-b76f010 where Garry Kasparov advocates that Ukraine should be a NATO member. There is no mention of Article 5 being triggered or not. Any counter views like “this is unwise because it would provoke Russia” also seem to imply that Article 5 doesn’t simply decide the issue in favor of war.

Comment: "Yet everyone is talking about NATO membership for Ukraine"   Are they?

Comment: We can't predict what would happen in the event that Ukraine joins NATO as if the join the terms could easily include that it would not result in article 5 or they could easily include that it will result in article 5 or they could say nothing about it There is too much unknown about what is happening behind the scenes to speculate on it.

Comment: Specifically, I’m thinking of Kasparov’s call for NATO membership for Ukraine in the Wall Street Journal and Biden’s current position against it. Proponents of either position seems to agree that NATO membership for Ukraine bears some risk of “escalation” but would not directly commit NATO states to go to war with Russia immediately. This implies that my prior understanding of NATO treaty obligations (specifically the part where an attack on one is considered an attack on all) is wrong. But I still don’t understand why.

Comment: I think the implication is that Article 5 relates to attacks on states that are *already members* of NATO. The Article is meant to deter anyone (or honestly, you know, Russia) from attacking a member state. If a state is already at war when it joins NATO, the purpose of membership as a deterrent doesn't apply, and so Article 5 isn't technically meaningful. All it would really do is commit NATO to supporting Ukraine in their pre-existing war, which they are already doing. The difficulty is that Russia might not see it that way, which could lead to unwanted escalations from their side.

Comment: Multiple news reports mentioned that it isn't POSSIBLE for Ukraine to join NATO while it is at war. That might be worth researching. If a clause forbids a country at war joining NATO, the whole question is moot.

Comment: Voting not to close - NATO alliance terms can provide an answer to this question. Moreover, even if there are any grey areas of the terms, the questioner is asking about the arguments and interpretations of the NATO terms put forward by politicians - this can again be factually answered by citing what the politicians (on both sides) are claiming.

Comment: @sfxedit Nato terms don't cover this situation unless you're just going to cite Article 5, in which case this is too trivial a question to ask. Article 5 has only been invoked once, in completely different circumstances, it's not clear on what basis Ukraine would join Nato, and there's no way to answer this without a vast amount of speculation.

Comment: @StuartF The question is, *"Why would Ukraine joining NATO at the present time not result in an immediate state of war between NATO members and Russia because of Article 5 obligations to defend a member state under attack?* The answer is that it would - Russia would see it as an immediate escalation, and open other fronts on NATO territories and / or NATO would be obliged to join the war. And that is why some NATO members don't want to allow Ukraine into NATO while the conflict is ongoing (which is again as per NATO rules - no country can join without unanimous approval of others).

Comment: @StuartF And note that questioner is asking what arguments are citied by the politicians demanding that Ukraine be immediately made a NATO member.

Comment: @Tom I edited my question in part to address the consideration that a country at war couldn’t join. I always assumed that was true. If not that it was banned, that NATO wouldn’t want to simply inherit the war in this way.

Comment: You're thinking of paper documents as rules that people have to follow. That's wrong. That's backwards. In reality, people decide what they're going to do, and then they write it down.

Comment: @Tom, William Dewey: NATO can take military action to defend non-members.  If NATO is already defending a nonmember that is at war, the war would not present a barrier to the nonmember becoming a member.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

tl;dr: Gray area

Article 5 states:

> The Parties agree that an armed attack against one or more of them in
> Europe or North America shall be considered an attack against them all

and Article 6 clarifies an armed attack:

> on the forces, vessels, or aircraft of any of the Parties

Neither article specifies what exactly an "armed attack" is, nor whether each individual strike, offensive or even bullet fired would constitute one or if it would consider the entire operation one "armed attack". It also does not have anything to say about an ongoing conflict at the time of joining.
If you wanted to, however, you could say that any shot fired at any soldier, tank, etc. of Ukraine after the moment of joining constitutes an armed attack and triggers Article 5.

As for the joining itself, there is [no checklist of NATO membership](https://1997-2001.state.gov/regions/eur/fs_members.html).

All this leaves considerable gray areas. From new reports and interviews [such as this one](https://www.npr.org/2023/06/03/1179979756/zelenskyy-accepts-ukraine-cannot-become-a-nato-member-until-the-war-ends), we can see that at least a number of important people do believe that if Ukraine were to join at this time, Article 5 would be triggered.

Comment: Article 6 limits Article 5 to specific areas and forces, vessels or aircraft **in or over these areas**. in 1951 is was changed to include the Asian part of Turkey so it could be changed to not include parts of Ukraine (although that would defeat the purpose of NATO)

Comment: @xyldke could be changed, yes. But as it is written right now, if Ukraine were to join NATO than attacks on Ukraine forces, vessels or aircraft would trigger Article 5. But, of course, politicians being who they are, if they really wanted they would find a way to argue that the actual attack began in 2022, before Ukraine joined. It would be a contrived argument, but it could be made.

Answer (score 7):

NATO membership for Ukraine would **not directly** lead to the other NATO members being at war with Russia. But they would have promised to restore the security of Ukraine.

> The Parties agree that an armed attack against one or more of them in Europe or North America shall be considered an attack against them all and [...] such action as it deems necessary, including the use of armed force, to restore and maintain the security of the North Atlantic area.

**In theory,** NATO could admit Ukraine and not "deem it necessary" to defend the entire territory of Ukraine with armed force. **In practice,** that seems unlikely unless the accession agreement clearly specifies which parts of Ukraine are NATO territory and which are not. (Remember the Falklands? British, but not NATO.)

The US President, among others, made it clear that in the present day, Article 5 means they will defend "every inch" of NATO territory. That's a political red line, while the text of the article says slightly less.

Comment: If the current support for Ukraine already would satisfy Article 5, that partly resolves my confusion.

Comment: @WilliamDewey, NATO **said** they would *defend*, say, Latvia, with much greater force than they *support* Ukraine right now. They don't want to put question marks over the level of support for current members.

Comment: With regards to the Falklands, it's worth noting that they are not "in Europe or North America" or North of the Tropic of Cancer, so not covered by Article V anyway. Interestingly, I suppose this would also technically mean that Guam, Saipan, and even the main islands of the U.S. state of Hawaii are not covered, as they are not in North America and are South of the Tropic of Cancer. But, amusingly, French Frigate Shoals and Midway Atoll would be covered, as they are North of the Tropic of Cancer. So, Russia can invade Honolulu without triggering Article V, but not Midway.

Comment: In any case, a state does not /join/ NATO , it is /admitted/ by existing members who would no doubt take any existing military situation into account.

Comment: Biden is, of course, the architect of Obama's infamously pointless *'Red Lines'* on chemical weapons.

Comment: @reirab Article 6 is relevant here, because it clarifies the territories and forces covered by Article 5. It's also the only Article that was changed so far (to include the Asian part of Turkey) [Here](https://scholarlycommons.law.emory.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1226&context=eilr) is a paper about its history.

Comment: @xyldke Right. That's where the Tropic of Cancer line I mentioned came from. Insular possessions of member states are included, but only ones North of the Tropic of Cancer, which leads to the amusing issue I mentioned of uninhabited places like Midway or French Frigate Shoals being covered, but not the main islands of Hawaii. Which is especially interesting in light of the history of Pearl Harbor.

Comment: @reirab while the territories you cite may be north of the Tropic of Cancer, they are not covered by the treaty.  The full phrase is "the North Atlantic area north of the Tropic of Cancer," and these territories are not in the Atlantic.

Comment: @phoog, see the Turkey clarification in Article 6 for how this would work. The NATO members are free to define the threaty area to include non-Atlantic territories if they like.

Comment: @phoog Ah, yeah, I think I had mentally inserted an 'or' in there when I originally read Article 6.

Comment: @o.m. Right, but that would require every member country to consent to amending the treaty as they did for Turkey, though, wouldn't it?

Comment: @o.m. how what would work?

Comment: @phoog, consider Germany during the Cold War. West Germany legally claimed that the final status of East and West Germany was not yet settled, and that the inner-German border was not an international border, yet West Germany was a NATO member. The situation was stable enough for that.

Comment: @reirab, every member would have to consent to Ukraine joining, which is a **much** greater hurdle than adjusting Article 6.

Comment: @o.m. I don't understand why you're addressing these comments to me.  They don't seem to be relevant to my comment about territories in the Pacific being outside the scope of the North Atlantic Treaty.

Comment: @o.m. I think phoog was just correcting my misreading of Article 6 (I had accidentally read it as island possessions in the North Atlantic area or North of the Tropic of Cancer rather than both in the North Atlantic area and North of the Tropic of Cancer,) not suggesting that the treaty couldn't be changed to include other places by consent of all parties. So, I had read it as currently including Midway when it doesn't. Of course, consent of all parties could make any change they want, including dissolving it entirely, admitting North Korea, Russia, and China, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It would not result NATO going into the Russia after Moscow, but I do not see how NATO makes any sense if they would not come to Ukraine, with they troops and all modern weapons.

The red line would be "we do not attack the **internationally recognized** (not Crimea, etc) territory of Russia directly". Of course, Russia has declared this line to be elsewhere, including statements that NATO is already at war with them and others that its territory now expands over annexed territories of Ukraine, mostly not recognized worldwide. NATO will need to risk ignoring this.

Comment: Also, they don't agree on what territories are and aren't part of Russia.

Comment: NATO will obviously take the own view into consideration: all former territory of Ukraine.

Comment: Indeed. But I can see how NATO attacking military targets in Crimea would risk World War III, and probably senior politicians and generals see that as well.

Comment: This is likely the reason why they are not accepting Ukraine into NATO so far right now, on that we seem in consensus.

Comment: Yeah, admitting Ukraine right now doesn't seem like it has any possible way to be helpful. The whole point of Article V of the NAT is to act as a deterrent to someone invading a NATO country in the first place. That effect is rather lost when admitting a country which is already presently invaded.

Comment: @gerrit perhaps this is just me being pedantic but for it to be a World War, doesn't that mean Russia needs allies who are actually fighting? I guess Belarus is their ally but I don't think India or China is going to commit troops to fight with them.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor Fair enough; a nuclear war where NATO states and Russia are destroying each other with nuclear weapons, then.  Bad enough even if the rest of the world stays neutral (World War I was also mostly a European war).  Whether we call that World War III will be the least of our worries.